# symfony 2 get Value from manyToOne confusion

Tags: symfony, many-to-one, getparameter

I have an entity which looks like

```
    .
.
.
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PrLeadBundle\Entity\Stock")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="stock_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $stock;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->stock = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}



/**
 * Add stock
 *
 * @param \PrLeadBundle\Entity\Stock $stock
 * @return ValueList
 */
public function addStock(\PrLeadBundle\Entity\Stock $stock)
{
    $this->stock[] = $stock;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove stock
 *
 * @param \PrLeadBundle\Entity\Stock $stock
 */
public function removeStock(\PrLeadBundle\Entity\Stock $stock)
{
    $this->stock->removeElement($stock);
}

/**
 * Get stock
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getStock()
{
    return $this->stock;
}
```

Now, If I try to access theese values I get an Join Column error.

I'm using :

```
  $Values = $entityManager->getRepository('PrLeadBundle:ValueList')->findBy(array('disabled' => '0','exportable'=>'1'), array('title' => 'ASC'));
foreach ($Values as $item){
    var_dump($item->getStock()->getId());
}
```

This is a bit confusing for me cause i ran into an :

> Attempted to call method "getId" on class
>   "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection". 500 Internal Server Error -
>   UndefinedMethodException

I did thsi for certain times in past, and I can also access the stock values in twig by using {{ item.stock.id }} ...

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: can you show us the entity Stock code, why you are using manyToMany if you want just a oneToMany Relation

Answer (score 1):

Because `$stock` variable is a `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`,
so instead of `$item->getStock()->getId()` you should try something like `$item->getStock()->first()->getId());` or `var_dump($item->getStock()` to see the structure before extracting the element.